# Configure vim to expand tabs except for some file types

Tags: vim, indentation

People usually ask how to expand tabs for specific file types -- I want the expansion done on the inverse-set: how to expand tabs for all except for some file types.

I already have a global setting for all files:

```
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab softtabstop=4 autoindent
```

I wish to exclude all files without a filetype and for files ending in `.txt`. I've already tried stuff like

```
if &filetype == ""
   setlocal noexpandtab noautoindent
endif
```

and

```
autocmd FileType "" set noexpandtab
```

to no avail. (The first matches my perl files, the second doesn't match anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the `File Type` event is only triggered when a filetype has actually been *set*, which, in your case, is the exact opposite. I would try something like:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == "" | setlocal noxpandtab | setlocal noautoindent | endif
```

That should work, maybe you need some other event types than only `BufEnter`. Also don't forget to wrap your autocmd's in an `augroup`, or they might be executed multiple times, see http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html ;) good luck!

Comment: (1) Would you be so kind to expand your answer with an explanation of why my `if &filetype ...` approach didn't work? (I assume your first sentence refers to why my `autocmd FileType "" ...` approach wouldn't work)

Comment: (2) After reading the article you linked, I couldn't understand when vim would source its `.vimrc` file *on its own*. I'm certainly never doing it manually, should I still care about `augroup`s?

Comment: (2) first: vim will only source the `.vimrc` once after startup, so you don't have to worry in that case, but you should keep it in mind. When I work on my `.vimrc`, I regularly source it using `:so %`, because I don't want to restart vim after every change(losing windows and tabs), in which case `autocmd`s would be added multiple times.

Comment: to (1): If you just put the `if &filetype` in your `.vimrc`(thats what it looked like to me), the `if` will _only_ be evaluated once, and thats at vim startup. If you want it to be executed for every new buffer/file, thats what `autocmd`s are there for :)